# Run queries on Groovy/Grails startup

Tags: grails, gsp

I am currently learning Grails/Groovy (I am very new) and trying to set a up eCommerce type of a site.  I want the first page that the user sees to be a list of all of our merchandise categories.  Every category has items. If I hard code the categories into the home page, I am able to click on each link (each category) and go to my controller and query each item for that specific category.  But I can't figure out how to query for the categories on start-up as it doesn't appear that any controller runs for my index.gsp.

What is the best way to go about querying for my categories on start-up, and then possibly every time I come back to my index.gsp page?  Below is the code I have used to hard-code the categories:

```
<li><g:link id="2" controller="category" action="show">Category 1</g:link></li>
<li><g:link id="3" controller="category" action="show">Category 2</g:link></li>
```

Once I click these links, my controller works fine and the items for that category are listed properly.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default index.gsp does not map to a controller (as you figured out). In the `URLMappings.groovy`, you can change the default URL `"/"` to map to whatever controller you want. That controller can query the database and show the categories (so your default controller might be the `CategoriesController` for example).

The docs for URL Mappings are http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Plug-ins/URL%20mappings.html

Answer (score 2):

Although the UrlMappings.groovy config change should be the preferred solution but, if you don't want to do that then you can also issue a redirect in your index.gsp. So your index file will look like:

```
<% response.sendRedirect("${request.contextPath}/category/index") %>
```